# error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

I keep on getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" when I try to run this program in chrome. I do not now what I am doing wrong, and and any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script>
    var x = "hey";
    var counter = 1;
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    var div = document.getElementById("box");
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    var sound = document.getElementById("sound");
    var array=[ "thanks for clicking", "keep on clicking", "click one more time", "why do you keep on clicking me?", "stop clicking me!"];
function thing(file){
    var y = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
        if (x == y){
            while (y == x){
                var y = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
        }   
        }
    form1.text.value=y;

    x = y;
sound.innerHTML = "<embed src=\""+file+"\"hidden=\"true\"autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\"/>";

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1">
<input type="button" id="button" value="click" onClick="thing('sound.mp3')" />
    <input type="text" id="text" value="hey" />
</form>
<div id="sound">
<p>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your script is executing before the `<body>` loads. Therefore none of the elements you try to access exist and `getElementById` returns `null`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Wait for the window to load:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    //yourJSCodeHERE
}
```

or move your JS after the `</body>` tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I moved the JS to go after my div and it worked!

Comment: If your code snippet works specifically after the html is loaded, you can easily place the js code right before the end of the </body> tag... similar to how google analytics ask you to do the same.