# Result is correct but console shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting the desired output but the console is showing

> Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of
>   null

I have tried other [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693718/error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null) but they give me different issues.

Here is my code:

```js
var dogs = ["Jimmy","Rudolph","Rocky","Sweezy"];

for (var i = 0; i <= dogs.length; i++) {
 document.getElementById('dogName' + (i+1) ).innerHTML = dogs[i];
 console.log(dogs[i]);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h3>My name is <span id="dogName1"></span></h3>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/140/180/animals">
</div>
<div>
    <h3>My name is <span id="dogName2"></span></h3>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/140/180/animals">
</div>
<div>
    <h3>My name is <span id="dogName3"></span></h3>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/140/80/animals">
</div>
<div>
    <h3>My name is <span id="dogName4"></span></h3>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/140/180/animals">
</div>
```

Comment: try changing <= to <. your loop is running one time too many, and the last element dogName5 doesn't exist

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich that did it.

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich so it was iterating through an empty index at the end?

Comment: yes. because it ran once when i=4 and you are doing i+1 (which gives 5, which doesn't exist)

Comment: Tip: If you had moved `console.log(dogs[i]);` before `document.getElementById` it would have been easier for you to spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing <= to <. your loop is running one time too many, and the last element dogName5 doesn't exist

```
var dogs = ["Jimmy","Rudolph","Rocky","Sweezy"];

for (var i = 0; i < dogs.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('dogName' + (i+1) ).innerHTML = dogs[i];
    console.log(dogs[i]);
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<h3>My name is <span id="dogName1"></span></h3>
<img src="https://placeimg.com/140/180/animals">
</div>
<div>
<h3>My name is <span id="dogName2"></span></h3>
<img src="https://placeimg.com/140/180/animals">
</div>
<div>
    <h3>My name is <span id="dogName3"></span></h3>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/140/80/animals">
</div>
<div>
   <h3>My name is <span id="dogName4"></span></h3>
   <img src="https://placeimg.com/140/180/animals">
</div>
```